# Join two NSBezierPaths

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, graphics

I have a function that returns a NSBezierPath. Now I call that function two times to get two paths. I now want to join them. When I try the function

```
[newPath appendBezierPath:[self funcThatRetursBezierPath]];
```

They get joined as a single path but there is no line(link) from the original bezierPath (`newPath`) to the new one. I want a line from the end of `newPath` to the beginning of the `functionThatReturnsBezierpath`.

**EDIT**

I just want a line or arc between two bezier paths. Is there a corresponding function for the same.

Comment: Did you try to redraw your context after append path?

Comment: @kolx I'm drawing only after append. But its coming as two separate lines. I want a line between the paths.

Comment: you need to add line between two path: [path1 addLineToPoint:(Point of another path2 after append)];

Comment: @kokx the function just returns bezier path and I don't have the starting point. its generated based on a given trignometric function.

Comment: Do you have any control over how the second path is created? If it starts with `moveToPoint:` then appending it will start a new subpath without connection to the previous subpath.

Comment: @MartinR the function is created by me. The function begins with a moveToPoint

Comment: You could introduce a boolean parameter "append" to that method. If `append == YES`, the created path starts with `lineToPoint` instead of `moveToPoint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `appendBezierPath:` states:

> ... This method does not explicitly try to connect the subpaths in the
>   two objects, although the operations in `aPath` may still cause that
>   effect.

If the second path starts with `moveToPoint:` then appending it will start a new subpath without connection to the previous subpath.

I would recommend to add a boolean parameter "append" to your 
path creating method. If `append == YES`, the created path starts with `lineToPoint:` instead of `moveToPoint:`.

Comment: actually this raises an exception ("No current point for line") if you try to create a NSBezierPath without moving to a point first.

Comment: Instead of adding a boolean "append" parameter (which runs into the problem of not being able to create a new path without moving to a point first), you can add an NSBezierPath parameter for an (optional) existing path -- if an existing path is supplied, append to it, otherwise start a new path.